# Ошибка при навигации в викторине android

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

Делаю викторину-опросник в приложении. Есть две кнопки вперед и назад. Есть массив вопросов которые я показываю. Обязательное условие - возможность показать 5 последних отвеченных вопросов. С сервера приходят все вопросы (в том числе и отвеченные), все ответы (если они есть). После того как все получено, я фильтрую не отвеченные вопросы и складываю в  массив. Так же в отдельный массив я складываю последние 5 вопросов с ответами. Сейчас работает так - после получения, фильтрации я отображаю первый не отвеченный вопрос, при этом кнопка показа предыдущего вопроса активна а показа следующего неактивна (пока нет ответа). Я сейчас могу кнопкой назад просмотреть 5 отвеченных вопросов с их вариантами ответов. Могу пройти от начала массива и до конца, а потом кнопка назад становится неактивна пока не нажимается кнопка вперед. Суть проблемы в том что я могу нормально перемещаться по вопросам только если кнопкой назад дойти до последнего отвеченного вопроса, если к примеру я захочу посмотреть первый отвеченный вопрос, а потом вернуться к первому не отвеченному вопросу то мне придется нажать на кнопку "Вперед" два раза. Вот код обработки нажатий на кнопки:

```
updateAdapter(0, questionsIndex, answersOptions, 1, ArrayList<Int>())
questionsIndex += 1

next_question.setOnClickListener {
 if (questionsIndex != questionType1.lastIndex) {
 if (userAnswerId != null) {
   Singleton.apiService().sendAnswer("Bearer " + context!!.getSharedPreferences("app_data", 0).getString("access_token", "")!!, OutAnswerModel(questionType1[questionsIndex - 1].id!!, userAnswerId!!))
  .enqueue(object : Callback<OutAnswerModel> {
  override fun onResponse(call: Call<OutAnswerModel>, response: Response<OutAnswerModel>) {
 if (response.isSuccessful) {
  lastAnswersArray.add(0, questionType1[questionsIndex - 1])
  userAnswers.add(0, userAnswerId!!)
  userAnswerId = null
  userAnswers.removeAt(userAnswers.lastIndex)
  lastAnswersArray.removeAt(lastAnswersArray.lastIndex)

  updateAdapter(0, questionsIndex, answersOptions, 1, ArrayList<Int>())
  questionsIndex += 1
 }
  }


   override fun onFailure(call: Call<OutAnswerModel>, t: Throwable) {

}
})
} else if (answerIndex in -1..4) {
when {
answerIndex >= 0 -> {
updateAdapter(1, answerIndex, answersOptions, 2, userAnswers[answerIndex])
}
answerIndex < 0 -> {
answerIndex = 0
updateAdapter(0, questionsIndex - 1, answersOptions, 1, ArrayList<Int>())
}
}
answerIndex -= 1
prev_question.isEnabled = true
}

} else {
workingWithViews(1)

textSetter(finalText!![0], finalText[1], finalText[2])
next.isEnabled = false
Handler().postDelayed({
next.isEnabled = true
}, 1000)
}

}

if (lastAnswersArray.isNotEmpty()) {
prev_question.setOnClickListener {
updateAdapter(1, answerIndex, answersOptions, 2, userAnswers[answerIndex])

if (answerIndex != lastAnswersArray.lastIndex) {
answerIndex += 1
} else {
prev_question.isEnabled = false
}
}
} else {
answerIndex -= 1
prev_question.isEnabled = false


 }
```

вероятнее всего где-то мой алгоритм дает сбой но не могу понять где именно и как починить. Вроде все учел но работает не так как нужно. Возможно объяснил не очень понятно, поэтому если что-то кто-то не поймет спрашивайте.

### UPD

проблему алгоритма кажется смог локализовать. При нажатии на кнопку "назад" я увеличиваю индекс ответа на 1:

```
if (answerIndex != lastAnswersArray.lastIndex) {
answerIndex += 1 // тут 
} else {
prev_question.isEnabled = false
}
```

дальше я нажимаю кнопку "вперед" и уменьшаю индекс на 1:

```
else if (answerIndex in -1..4) {
answerIndex -= 1 // тут 
when {
answerIndex >= 0 -> {
updateAdapter(1, answerIndex, answersOptions, 2, userAnswers[answerIndex])
}
answerIndex < 0 -> {
answerIndex = 0
updateAdapter(0, questionsIndex - 1, answersOptions, 1, ArrayList<Int>())
}}
prev_question.isEnabled = true
}
```

и получается что при нажатии "назад" мы индекс увеличили, а при нажатии "вперед" уменьшили в итоге нужно нажимать два раза чтобы индекс уменьшился достаточно для срабатывания условия. Как починить пока не придумал :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все довольно просто оказалось на самом деле. Я нагородил кучу массивов и кучу индексов которые в итоге меня запутали. Что я сделал в итоге: один массив и один индекс. Вначале массива будет 5 отвеченных вопросов, дальше не отвеченные. Навигация тоже ультра-простая, кнопка "назад":

```
  prev_question.setOnClickListener {
     questionsIndex -= 1

     if (questionsIndex >= 0) {
       if (questionsIndex == 0) {
          prev_question.isEnabled = false
       }
       updateAdapter(questionsIndex, answersOptions, 2, userAnswers[questionsIndex])
      }
    }
```

кнопка "вперед", фрагмент где была ошибка:

```
else if (questionsIndex in -1..4) {
     questionsIndex += 1

     if (questionsIndex <= 4) {
        updateAdapter(questionsIndex, answersOptions, 2, userAnswers[questionsIndex])
     } else {
       updateAdapter(questionsIndex, answersOptions, 1, ArrayList<Int>())
     }
    prev_question.isEnabled = true
}
```

теперь index начинается не с 0 а с 5, то есть будет показываться первый не отвеченный вопрос. Дальше все по коду понятно надеюсь. Не нужно было ничего городить и строить, все оказалось проще и понятнее чем вначале. Если у кого-то будут вопросы, или пожелания - задавайте/предлагайте :)